# UV Select mode resets to Island

Tags: uv, selection-tools

Any time I switch to verts/edges/faces mode in the UV editor and make a first selection (which works fine), the selection mode automatically resets to islands. Which is extremely annoying when you want to select several vertices. Right now my only workaround is to switch back to required mode after every selection.

I've been digging through settings of UV editor, hotkeys and the internet, and saw no clear mentions of such behavior. Any ideas what might be the reason?

Blender version 2.93.1 / control scheme 2.7X

Comment: Do you have selection synced with the mesh?

Comment: No, and in fact, when I switch to synced selection, the mode doesn't change and I can select several vertices as usual. Granted, there is no island selection mode in synced in the first place.

This mode is also something I avoid using whenever possible, with its forced selection of multiple elements when selecting edges of UV islands, and incomprehensible clutter when working with overlapping islands.